# Flutter:- Webview error in Payment gateway

Tags: android, html, ios, flutter

This HTML data I am passing to webview, I am using `flutter_webview_plugin: ^0.3.10+2`.

```
<html>
    <body onload="document.f.submit();">
      <form 
        id='f'
        name='f'
        action="${data.pAYMENTPAGE}" method="post">
        <input  type="hidden"  id="PaymentID" name="PaymentID"  value = $paymentId />
      </form> 
   </body>
  </html>
```

Сan anyone help with the following error ?

OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
D/OpenSSLLib( 7523): OpensslErr:Module:12(177:); file:external/boringssl/src/crypto/asn1/asn1_lib.c ;Line:168;Function:ASN1_get_object
I/chromium( 7523): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)]

A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at https://test.benefit-gateway.com/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`.

You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.